# Pentaho SolutionEngine.ERROR_0007 on Red Hat

Tags: pentaho

I installed some days ago Pentaho BA (full install) on a Red Hat system. I installed version 5.0.7.1-x64 because the latest 5.1 version gave me problems just after the installation. The 5.0.7.1 version still have some problems (exceptions in logs) but it was working fine, until today. Today I logged in into the PUC and I found that there are some severe issues in the functionalities of the server: after logging in I get only the upper menu and not the content of the home page. I can access and see the "Browse Files" menu, but when I select a dashboard or a report it doesn't load: it just loads the upper bar like for the home page and the title but the dashboard is completely empty. Not even the "grid" for the various reports.

I copied the content of the log file catalina.out and you can find it here http://pastebin.com/hshXekFM
From line 33 there's the part where the server loads the login pageFrom line 51 it's after the login.

Here you can find the content of the catalina.2014-07-09.log http://pastebin.com/L7ReLdpt
and here the pentaho.log file:

> 2014-07-09 09:53:53,732 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine] 2bc1b7a9-073e-11e4-8cb0-005056a82a08:SOLUTION-ENGINE:/public/bi-developers/Secure/global-department-list.xaction: SolutionEngine.ERROR_0007 - Action sequence execution failed
>   2014-07-09 10:20:56,969 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine] f39bcc4a-0741-11e4-8cb0-005056a82a08:SOLUTION-ENGINE:/public/bi-developers/rules/session-region-list.xaction: SolutionEngine.ERROR_0007 - Esecuzione dell'Action Sequence fallita
>   2014-07-09 10:20:57,185 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine] f3be215b-0741-11e4-8cb0-005056a82a08:SOLUTION-ENGINE:/public/bi-developers/rules/session-region-list.xaction: SolutionEngine.ERROR_0007 - Esecuzione dell'Action Sequence fallita
>   2014-07-09 10:20:57,224 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine] f3c3035c-0741-11e4-8cb0-005056a82a08:SOLUTION-ENGINE:/public/bi-developers/rules/session-region-list.xaction: SolutionEngine.ERROR_0007 - Esecuzione dell'Action Sequence fallita
>   2014-07-09 10:20:57,322 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine] f3d2bacd-0741-11e4-8cb0-005056a82a08:SOLUTION-ENGINE:/public/bi-developers/rules/session-region-list.xaction: SolutionEngine.ERROR_0007 - Esecuzione dell'Action Sequence fallita
>   2014-07-09 10:22:17,301 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine] 23814d9e-0742-11e4-8cb0-005056a82a08:SOLUTION-ENGINE:/public/bi-developers/rules/session-region-list.xaction: SolutionEngine.ERROR_0007 - Action sequence execution failed
>   2014-07-09 10:22:17,343 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine] 238656af-0742-11e4-8cb0-005056a82a08:SOLUTION-ENGINE:/public/bi-developers/rules/session-region-list.xaction: SolutionEngine.ERROR_0007 - Action sequence execution failed
>   2014-07-09 10:22:17,434 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.engine.services.solution.SolutionEngine] 23941250-0742-11e4-8cb0-005056a82a08:SOLUTION-ENGINE:/public/bi-developers/rules/session-region-list.xaction: SolutionEngine.ERROR_0007 - Action sequence execution failed
>   2014-07-09 10:22:17,492 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.ActionAdapterQuartzJob] ActionAdapterQuartzJob.ERROR_0004 - Action "org.pentaho.platform.plugin.action.builtin.ActionSequenceAction" failed to run as a quartz job
>   java.lang.Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException
>           at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.ActionAdapterQuartzJob.invokeAction(ActionAdapterQuartzJob.java:271)
>           at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.ActionAdapterQuartzJob.execute(ActionAdapterQuartzJob.java:133)
>           at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.BlockingQuartzJob.execute(BlockingQuartzJob.java:38)
>           at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:199)
>           at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException
>           at org.pentaho.platform.web.http.api.resources.RepositoryFileStreamProvider.getInputStream(RepositoryFileStreamProvider.java:118)
>           at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.ActionAdapterQuartzJob$1.call(ActionAdapterQuartzJob.java:176)
>           at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.ActionAdapterQuartzJob$1.call(ActionAdapterQuartzJob.java:166)
>           at org.pentaho.platform.engine.security.SecurityHelper.runAsUser(SecurityHelper.java:179)
>           at org.pentaho.platform.engine.security.SecurityHelper.runAsUser(SecurityHelper.java:168)
>           at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.ActionAdapterQuartzJob.invokeAction(ActionAdapterQuartzJob.java:250)
>           ... 4 more
>   2014-07-09 10:22:17,502 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.ActionAdapterQuartzJob] ActionAdapterQuartzJob.ERROR_0001 - Property "ActionAdapterQuartzJob-ActionClass" or "ActionAdapterQuartzJob-ActionId" must be set in the job data map
>   2014-07-09 10:22:17,502 ERROR [org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.ActionAdapterQuartzJob] ActionAdapterQuartzJob.ERROR_0002 - Failed to create an instance of action "unknown"
>   org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.ActionAdapterQuartzJob$LoggingJobExecutionException: ActionAdapterQuartzJob.ERROR_0001 - Property "ActionAdapterQuartzJob-ActionClass" or "ActionAdapterQuartzJob-ActionId" must be set in the job data map
>           at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.ActionAdapterQuartzJob.resolveClass(ActionAdapterQuartzJob.java:79)
>           at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.ActionAdapterQuartzJob.execute(ActionAdapterQuartzJob.java:117)
>           at org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.BlockingQuartzJob.execute(BlockingQuartzJob.java:48)
>           at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:199)
>           at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:546)

How can I solve this?
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the file sessionStartupActions.xml and comment out the lines that are calling those .xaction files.

That happens when it tries to call the actions for the sample data that you probably didn't install.

Comment: Where can I find this file??

Comment: @DaveRanjan /server/biserver-ee/pentaho-solutions/system/sessionStartupActions.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely to be Quartz configuration issue.

I would suggest to re-check quartz configuration files - have they been modified by patch or manually since last job/transformation was successfully scheduled?

This may be a start point.

If this is not a solution don't hesistate to [fire a bug](http://jira.pentaho.com) - at least developers could provide more sophistaicated error message for this case.

For enterprise users pentaho provides official support - so don't waste time for forums and kick they directly.

Otherwise - quartz is widely used so at least there is some configurations where it is really works without this exception - so the question is to find what is the difference between this one and other.

Hope it will help a little bit. :(